# How to mention parameter dependency in swagger

Tags: swagger

I have 2 api calls such that the parameters required to call the second Api depends on the response generated from the first Api call.

Is there anyway in swagger to show such dependency in UI.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can document it verbally in an operation description but you can't document the dependency of one operation on the other.

This implies a flow of API calls which means they are not quite stateless, and that goes against the standard REST API design.